# Using preg_replace to "update" searched string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So i have this string:

```
$str='<li>Smartphone: Da</li>
      <li>Touchscreen: Da</li>
      <li>Tastatura QWERTY: Nu</li>
      <li>Tip tastatura: Standard</li>
      <li>Rezolutie senzor (Mp): 5</li>
      <li>SAR (W/kg ): 1.17</li>';
```

And what i am trying to do is to add some 'strong' tags to the word between li tags and the ':' character. I tried getting all the wanted words in an array with:

```
     preg_match_all('/<li>(.*?):/', $str, $matches);
```

and then trying to transform them from there but it didn't help me so much. So now i am trying to use preg_replace but i don't want to give a substitute word as a parameter because it differs from one li to another. In other words i want to do something like this:

```
    preg_replace('/<li>(.*?):/',"<strong>'/<li>(.*?):/'</strong>",$str);
```

So i want to search for the text between li tags and ':' and then put strong tags before and after in order for it to become bold.

Sorry if my explanation was bad but i fairly new to regular expressions and don't really know the vocabulary. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The replacement expression you were looking for is:

```
preg_replace('/<li>([^:]*):/','<li><strong>\1</strong>:',$str);
```

The `[^:]*` part matches all characters which are not ":" (otherwise the regular expression would be "greedy", see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy). The \1 part will insert the selected (see "()") part back to the expression.

Comment: Tried this one too, and i can still see no changes in $str. Any idea what i am missing?

Comment: preg_replace will return the result, so you have to use it like this:
`$str = preg_replace(..., $str);`
Did you use it this way?

Comment: Dumb me.. Sorry for wasting your time like that i have my head wrapped in this thing for hours and now i forget the little things. Ontopic: It worked, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
/<li\b[^>]*>\K[^<:]+(?=:)/i
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3HuV0N9r2XHclZAP)

---

```
preg_replace('/<li\b[^>]*>\K[^<:]+(?=:)/i', '<strong>$0</strong>', $str);
```

**[PHP Demo](http://ideone.com/MSv8NA)**

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Though you should avoid parsing & manipulating HTML like this but if you are aware of all issues of HTML parsing with regex and still want to use regex:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=<li>)(.+?)(?=:)/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $str);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to replace anything in $str, although your expression seems to match what i want. What am i missing?

Comment: +1 :: @DragosBecsan - Even this answer is not optimized or perfect, it works - check http://ideone.com/Jb2DcV

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=<li>)([^:]*)/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $str);
print_r($str);
```

**Output:**

```
<li><strong>Smartphone</strong>: Da</li>
<li><strong>Touchscreen</strong>: Da</li>
<li><strong>Tastatura QWERTY</strong>: Nu</li>
<li><strong>Tip tastatura</strong>: Standard</li>
<li><strong>Rezolutie senzor (Mp)</strong>: 5</li>
<li><strong>SAR (W/kg )</strong>: 1.17</li>
```

Comment: undeleted since you seem to be having problems with the other answers.